# HTML tables not working in Internet Explorer 7

Tags: html, html-table, internet-explorer-7

I have a HTML table where I:

1. Include explicit table width.
2. Include explicit width on the first <td> row.
3. I have images in the columns but I include height and width tags on the images so the browser should know in advance the sizing.
4. Using

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   ```

This works fine in Internet Explorer 8, Firefox and Chrome.

Internet Explorer 7 doesn't seem to follow the col width specified as one column I have set as much larger than the other but it shows up the same size as the others.

What am I missing?

Here is some of the table HMTL and CSS:

CSS

```
 #mainApplicationsTable
 {
    table-layout:fixed;
 }
```

HTML:

```
<table border='0' class='altTable' width='320px' id='mainApplicationsTable'>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>1</th>
<th>2</th>
<th>3</th>
<th>4</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr class='odd' recnum='51'>
  <td width='190px'><div class='appDetailsClic'k id='51' >2</div></td>
  <td width='30px'><img width='16px' height='16px' title= 'a' border='0'  src="../../images/image.png"></td> 
  <td width='30px'><img width='16px' height='16px' title= 'Server' border='0' src="../../images/2.png"></td>
  <td width='30px'><img width='16px' height='16px' title= 'Server' border='0' src="../../images/2.png"></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: You're missing the html showing us your problem.  Please update your post with the html of the table exhibiting the issue.

Comment: If you're using XHTML strict then you should have quotes around your attributes - might be triggering quirks mode in IE7.

Comment: Please validate your HTML before asking others to figure it out. The lack of quotes looks invalid

Comment: that was actually a typo  . . this is now fixed . . same issue

Comment: 190 + 30 +30+30 = 280 and i have cellpadding that adds up to the rest.  do i not include the padding in my totaling ?

Comment: XHTML Strict doesn't allow the border attribute on an img element, so you've still not got valid markup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't included explicit widths in your first row. The first row is actually the one containing the `<th>` elements. Since they don't have widths, the fixed layout algorithm gives them all the same width. Move the width declarations to that row, or to some `<col>` elements at the front.

You're also going to have trouble because the given widths don't add up to 320. Incidentally, `width="320px"` is invalid; there is no unit in HTML measurements, that's only available in CSS. Either use `width="320"`, or, from a style, `width: 320px;`. The same goes for the image width/heights.